VS Code shows dummy errors despite successful builds; restarting VS Code temporarily resolves the issue—suggestions?
I’m encountering some wrong errors in Haskell while coding in VS Code, such as "not in scope," "not imported-exported" or "package not found." To fix this, I have to quit VS Code and reopen it. These errors don’t affect the functionality, as the project builds, runs, and passes tests correctly, but my code ends up with lots of false errors - red underlines. Do you have any suggestions?

Im using Stack / Vscode (Version: 1.95.3 (Universal)
Commit: f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813)
Mac Mini M1
ghcup 0.1.30.0
stack 3.1.1
hls   2.9.0.1
cabal 3.10.3.0 ,  3.12.1.0
ghc   9.10.1

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling almost everything possible.

I've had the same issue multiple times and clearing vscodes cache fixed it for me personally. what is your version of haskell, I'm  sure your haskell version is updated to the latest.
clearing cache worked for me

Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you please explain what you mean by clearing the cache? I’m using a universal image on my Mac, and technically, it caches all of my settings. Does clearing the cache mean deleting all of my settings, themes, extensions, etc.? Am I right, or is there a way I’m not aware of?

On macOS, the Cache and CachedData folders are located under:
$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code
or:
~/Library/Application\ Support/Code
The easiest way to clean the cache on macOS is to use the rm command
Cleaning the cache in VSCode typically does not delete your settings, but it does remove temporary files and cached data related to extensions and performance.
i would Highly recommend making a backup of your settings and extensions before doing this in case for some reason it does remove them (but it typically doesn't)
